# Execute code before controller's action

Tags: symfony

I would like execute code before all actions in my project (to calculate an important global variable).
How to set a pre-action function in my controllers ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no *pre-action* method in Symfony2. You have to use [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events) for that purpose.

Comment: I need to add that although there isn't a pre-action method per se, the event `kernel.controller` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 16):

Probably using listeners is more elegant way to implement "after controller initialized tasks", but there is more simplified way to do it:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Override method to call #containerInitialized method when container set.
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    parent::setContainer($container);
    $this->containerInitialized();
}

/**
 * Perform some operations after controller initialized and container set.
 */
private function containerInitialized()
{
     // some tasks to do...
}
```

Insert this code into your controller, or, if you prefer you can even insert it into some base parent abstraction of your controllers.

because container will be set to each controller when its initialized, we can override `setContainer` method to perform some tasks after container set.

Comment: Interesting! I will test that :)

Comment: This needs `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;`

Comment: Nice. I made now an AbstractController class that executes codes for all extending subcontrollers (before they are going to perform actions).

Comment: Please don't do this, that's a very very very very very bad way to do this

Comment: @Benoît : Could you explain why it is a so very bad way ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: One of the reasons why it might be not the best workaround is, by the order of initialization of autowired services, some services might not be available at the step of Controller setContainer, eg the very common Request service is not available at that moment, which is a fundamental dependency to work with at a controller generally

Answer (score 11):

You should especially read this documentation page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html