# Symfony2 set class variable with init or construct methods

Tags: symfony

Have recently been using Symfony2 after using ZF for some time.

I am having problems trying to do something relatively simple, I think.

The following code is within a controller:

```
private $current_setid = "";

public function __construct() {
    $current_set = $this->getCurrentSet();
    if ($current_set == "") {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('selectset'));
    }
    $this->current_setid = $current_set;
}

public function getCurrentSet() {
    $session = $this->get("session");
    $set = $session->get('set');
    return $set;
}

public function setCurrentSet($setid) {
    $session = $this->get("session");
    $session->set('set', "$setid");
}
```

If I use __construct() I get errors like:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
```

I have tried using __init() and init() both of which do not seem to get called.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to look into event listeners?

Comment: You should think about putting this in a event listener for kernel.request or kernel.controller I think. The architecture differs here from ZF2 and other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting your session like they do in official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html)?

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

$foo = $session->get('foo');
```

Comment: hm, strange. Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response namespace being used?

Comment: and yeah, if you're overloading constructor, you should call parent::__construct first also

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in ... using parent::__construct();

Answer (score 0):

Basically `get` fetch dependencies from container and container in the Controller is injected using [setter dependency injection](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection). You just not have container in the time of `__construct` yet.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913182/execute-code-before-controllers-action as well

Comment: So basically you are saying there is not an easy way to do this - it must be done with event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up opting for placing a check in every method in the class. Seems silly to have to do that but I find I often have to do that in Symfony2 with the lack of init, postDispatch type methods like ZF has.

Even trying to remove the check to another method was counter productive as I still had to check the return from that method as $this->redirect does not seem to work unless it is within an Action method. For example:

```
public function isSetSet() {
    $current_set = $this->getCurrentSet();
    if ($current_set == "") {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('selectset');
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

public function someAction() {
    $check = $this->isSetSet();
    if($check != TRUE){
        return $check;
    }
    ...
}
```

So each method needs that 4 line check but the whole check can be done in 4 lines anyway so no need for that extra method:

```
public function anotherAction() {
    $current_setid = $this->getCurrentSet();
    if ($current_setid == "") {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('selectset'));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a few hours and walk through the process of setting up a listener for this.  It's really quite easy once you know how.  And very powerful.  Always difficult to make a transition from one framework to another.  But it is usually worth while to learn the details of the new one.