# Auto starting session in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

It seems Symfony 2.1 does not auto start sessions. Is there a way for me to auto start them?

I have an application that requires user's session id in several actions, but there is no way to know which one will need it first, so I can not start it on demand, I need it to be there when I request it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need user's session id in some place from already started session, and if there is no session started yet, you want to do it

In this case try:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session; // use sessions

class yourController extends Controller
{
    public function yourAction()
    { 

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); // Get started session
        if(!$session instanceof Session)
            $session = new Session(); // if there is no session, start it

        $value = $session->getId(); // get session id


        return $this->render('YourSampleBundle:your:your.html.twig',array(
                'session_id' => $value
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: I would prefer for symfony to initiate it for me regardless of which action is called. is there a way?

Comment: @DavidW I think the only method to achieve it wolud be using `Event` and `EventListener` to execute it pre-every action in all bundles. some links: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913182/execute-code-before-controllers-action), [sf docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events), [other method](https://matt.drollette.com/2012/06/calling-a-method-before-every-controller-action-in-symfony2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the framework session configuration (defined in your config.xml) to auto start the session.

However, this is depecated. Sessions by design are started on demand.

```
<framework:config>
    <framework:session auto-start="true"/>
</framework:config>
```

My question would be why would you want to initialize a session unless you're using it?

Comment: That does not work, like you said, it's deprecated. I don't want to manually start a session. I need it because I need the session id of the user so I can identify certain actions user takes but none of it is stored in sessions so there is really nothing to do on demand.