# Run method before all controllers symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to run transparently it method before all controllers. How I need to do this?

```
protected function getFrontBreadcrumb()
{
    $breadcrumbs = $this->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
    $breadcrumbs->addItem("Главная", $this->get("router")->generate("front"));
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913182/execute-code-before-controllers-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use event listeners :)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events

Be careful not to ask questions that were already answered on Stack Overflow ^^