# run init() before every action in controller

Tags: symfony

I have

```
defaultController extends Controllers
{ 
   public function init( ){
   $myReq = $this->get('request');
   $this->sess = $this->myReq->getSession();
     ..other class variables
   }
   public function indexAction(){ $this->init(); }
   public function showAction(){ $this->init(); }
}
```

I am looking for a way to optimize this. I want class var to initialized in controller but don't want to call this method each and every time. Please note, it is old code and I am trying to make it better. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: This is what you need: [How to Set Up Before and After Filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) using the `kernel.controller` event from a `kernel.event_listener`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in sf1 you could use a function called preExecute that was launched before every action you had in your controller

I searched a little bit to find out if there was a equivalent method for sf2 and I found out technics where people use eventListeners to call a method before every actions

Here are the tutorials:

http://wickass.co.za/2013/04/01/adding-a-preexecute-method-to-symfony2-controllers/

http://symfony2.ylly.fr/symfony2-simulate-preexecute-postexecute-filters-actions-jordscream/

Symfony2 doc for eventListeners:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#events

Duplicate subject: 
[Execute code before controller's action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913182/execute-code-before-controllers-action)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener to Symfony's `kernel.controller` event. That event will be fired by Symfony before the controller is called.

The event listener's method will get an instance of [FilterControllerEvent](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html) class, which you could use do determine, which controller will be called (in case you do not want to call the `init` method before all of the controllers).

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-controller-event) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 2 the controller that you are extending implements the `ContainerAware` trait and you can override the setContainer method from that to basically do what you would normally do in your class `__construct`. Something like:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
... Other Use Statements ...

class YourController extends Controller
{
    protected $sess;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->sess = $container->get('session');
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function indexAction(){ 
        $this->sess->get('some_key'); // This now works
   }
}
```