# Symfony - where should be csrf validation done when not using symfony forms component?

Tags: php, symfony, oop

From the documentation I see it is done in controller:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    $submittedToken = $request->request->get('token');

    // 'delete-item' is the same value used in the template to generate the token
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete-item', $submittedToken)) {
        // ... do something, like deleting an object
    }
}
```

But when thinking about having slim controllers, I try to get things out of controller. So I am planning to add it to the service. Am I thinking well?

Comment: If you simply intend to make codes compact for readability, your have other options such as: 1)make another base controller and put this isCsrfTokenValid method 2)put them in filters (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913182/execute-code-before-controllers-action in) , etc. But by these resolutions, other readers might find it difficult to notice that such mechanisms are behind, compared with when you put them in service.

Comment: The problem when putting them in service feels like code duplication. And also this actually not that much of business logic. If I have business logic service, probably I do not want extra code everywhere which checks the validation of csrf token, would be good if that is done automatically. But another thing is - can it be done automatically if the csrf token ids are different. Or maybe I should use same ids? Then could add one funciton in filter which is executed before controller and only add to the forms the token input with same id.

Comment: I gave up using the Symfony Form component some time ago and replaced it with my own much simpler (and far less functional) Form class which has the same basic interface i.e. handleRequest, isSubmitted and isValid.  The csrf checking is done by the base Form class.  You could consider something similar.